# Ajax is giving me an error when I send data

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I am trying to submit a form by Ajax but I am unable to . I have multiple forms and I am using (this) to submit the data. I am getting the error `From error:0 error`.The alert messages are showing me that I have the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".submitform").click(function (){
        alert ($(this).parent().serialize());
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "reply_business.php",
                timeout:5000,
                data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    $('#load').show();
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $(this).parent().find('.sentreply').append(response);
                    $('.sentreply div:last').fadeOut(10).fadeIn(2000);
                    //uncomment for debugging purposes
                    //alert(response);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR) {
                   alert ('From error:' + jqXHR.status + ' ' +jqXHR.statusText);
                },
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    //uncomment for debugging purposes
                    //alert ('From complete:' + jqXHR.status + ' ' +jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + textStatus);
                    $('#load').hide();
           }
        });

    });
}); 

    </script>
```

I am creating the form below by the PHP code

```
foreach ($array['business_ids'] as $business) 
                  {              

                        ?>
<form >
  <input type="hidden" name="b_id" value="<?php echo $business ; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="<?php echo $sqlr['conversation_id']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="<?php echo $sqlr['query_id']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="<?php echo $sqlr['u_id']; ?>" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <textarea  name="reply">Type the reply here.</textarea>
  <input type="submit"  class="submitform" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php


                  }
```

I do not understand why Ajax isn't able to send the data.

Comment: How does the request look like in your network debugger? Does the server respond?

Comment: similiar problem, this may even solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661813/jqxhr-http-status-code-403-but-the-statuscode-is-0

Comment: @Bergi - The status comes as CANCELED for the requested page? any idea why is that . In that php i just saw the header which says `<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Is this the reason

Comment: Are you trying to do a CORS request?

Comment: @doniyor : Hmm.. but in my case I am on the same server and in same Dir too... what might be wrong ?

Comment: @Bergi : No,  Both are on the same domain , same folder.

Comment: I removed the Header but Still I am getting the Error. Its showing Canceled in the network debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the markup or the network traffic, we can only guess.  Perhaps $(this).parent() isn't the form?

It's typically safer to attach `$(form).submit()` than `$(button).click()` for this reason and because `$(button).click()` doesn't capture form submit by hitting the enter key.

**Edit** Here's an example:

```
<form id="theform">
    <input type="text" id="thetext" name="thetext" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
<form id="anotherform">
    <input type="text" id="anothertext" name="anothertext" />
    <input type="submit" value="save 2" />
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#theform").submit(function (e) {
            var data = {
                thetext: $("#thetext").val()
            };
            $.ajax("/the/server/url", {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (r) {
                    alert("done");
                }
            });
            // Technically you need only one or the other
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Robrich- But since i have 10-12 forms... If i do `$(form).submit() ` all of the form elements will be submitted. Any alternative ?

Comment: `$("#formid").submit()` will attach the submit only to this one form.

Comment: But the page will reload right. I wanted the ajax thing for avoiding the page reload.

Comment: As long as you `return false` at the end of the function (or `e.preventDefault()`), it won't do the default behavior -- in this case submit the form.  You're likely already doing that for the button click and link click to avoid them doing interesting things.

Comment: Could you please give me and example how could I impliment it ? Well i just want that out of the 10 form that I have the one which I click that is submitted in the database with ought reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have submitted the form after starting the Ajax request - and when the page is unloaded, the request is cancelled. Since your form has no `action`, the submit will just reload the current page so you might not notice it.

To prevent this, you will need to `preventDefault()` the catched event. Also, you should not handle just `click` events on submit-buttons, but rather the `submit`-event of the `<form>` itself.

Comment: The Ajax is being loaded on `$(document).ready(function() {` so .. and moreover the ` alert ($(this).parent().serialize());` is giving me the proper parameters to pass.  I am bit confused. well what should I do to pass the paraments of the form to the Php file. which is the easiest method '

Comment: Could you please give me and example how could I impliment it ? Well i just want that out of the 10 form that I have the one which I click that is submitted in the database with ought reloading the page ?

Comment: @robrich : Thank you so much :) I spent 10 hours to fix this. I am accepting your answer. But how did `e.preventDefault();
            return false;` make the difference?

Comment: Apologies, I edited the wrong post when I added my example.  That'll learn me to answer a question quickly when I've got one foot out the door.